# Notification when a ListViewItem scrolls into view

Tags: wpf

The following code is supposed to scroll an item into view and set focus to the first child control in the template:

```
lv.ScrollIntoView(lv.SelectedItem);

var lvi = lv.SelectedListViewItem();

//get the item's template parent
var templateParent = lvi.GetFrameworkElementByName<ContentPresenter>();

if (templateParent != null)  <--but it's always null
{
   var ctrl = templateParent.FindVisualChildren<FrameworkElement>().First();
   ctrl.Focus();
}
```

The problem is that if the `ListViewItem` is not visible, then `templateParent` is null, and this code doesn't work. And of course this code is only useful when the item isn't already visible.

Is there a way to scroll the item into view and then be notified *when it has come into view* so that the template will be non-null so that the `ctrl.Focus()` code would execute?

Comment: I have worked a lot with WPF, but wouldnt using Triggers and MVVM solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `RequestBringIntoView` event. Please refer to the following sample code.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lv.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
    lv.SelectedItem = 90;
    lv.ScrollIntoView(lv.SelectedItem);
    lv.RequestBringIntoView += Lv_RequestBringIntoView;
}

private void Lv_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    var container = lv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lv.SelectedItem);
    if (container != null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```